# Inverted switch does not work consistently

Tags: mosfet

I made an inverted switch circuit that turns off the LED when the switch SW1 is closed and turns on the LED when the switch SW1 is open.
I made several circuits and some of them do not work as they should. Each circuit is definitely the same as the other and uses the same components.

I can assure that the switch SW1 is fully closed but the led is still on. Testing the continuity of the switch SW1 confirms that it is closed.

Is there something that i missed ? how can i solve this issue?

if you are interested in the components:

N-MOSFET - [BSS138](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/BSS138-D.PDF)

LED - [QTLP650D4TR](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Everlight%20PDFs/QTLP650(C,D)-2,3,4,7,B.pdf)

Here is my schematics:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flPDnc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with the circuit structure.  One cause would be a bad FET.  Side note - 10 K seems very large.  I get about 150 microamps of LED current.  Is that enough for your application?

Comment: Did you take ESD precautions? You may have blown up the gate of the BSS138

Comment: @AnalogKid Will try to swap the transistors, i just need the led to light up at around 20mA of current what value do you recommend?

Comment: @Huisman by ESD you mean when i soldered it ? other than that no, the circuit diagram is what it is. I have not touched the Transistor when soldering, I placed it using plastic tweezers. As for the main power supply it has overvoltage and overcurrent protection.

Comment: What color is the LED? If you short out the drain and source of M1 does D1 light?

Comment: @AnalogKid I have tried replacing the mosfet twice just to be sure, the problem persisted,

Comment: For the current-limiting resistor, assume Vf(D1) = 1.8 V and Rdson(M1) = very small. R1 = E / I, so R1 = (3.3 - 1.8) / 0.02 = 75 ohms.

Comment: @Transistor the color of the LED is green.  product ID [QTLP650D4TR](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Everlight%20PDFs/QTLP650(C,D)-2,3,4,7,B.pdf).  Shorting the Drain and Source of the faulty part still remains to be lit up ( but that would make sense since the led has a path to ground.) shorting the resistor and Source does turn it off. Shorting the drain and source of the correctly function circuit turns on the led

Comment: @Jakequin shorting which resistor? R1? R2?

Comment: @Huisman Shorting R2 , my  apologgy all resistor i mentioned in my above comment is talking about R2. Please dont hold back on tests you want me to do, ill try my best to do it.

Comment: @Jakequin Could you please elaborate this "shorting the resistor (R2) and Source does turn it off." Do you short gate and source and will the LED turn off then? If so, check whether the switch SW1 is really connected to GND.

Comment: weird the component label seem to have been re arranged  ill change it back, what i ment was shorting the LED CURRENT LIMITING RESISTOR and the SOURCE of the mosfet the LED turns OFF.

Comment: @Huisman I did the shorting of the GATE and SOURCE it turned off.  I checked the continuity of the switch to ground and yes it connected to ground.

Comment: @Jakequin When that gate-source short was removed, the LED turned on again? If so, the BSS138 is correctly functioning.

Comment: If my previous comment holds, *measure* the gate voltage wrt GND when pressing an when releasing switch SW1. Check (solder) connections of the 1k resistor and the switch. while the board is *not* powered, measure the 10k resistor and measure the resistance of the pressed switch. (Continuity test =/= measurement, but indicaton)